# Angular momentum and Newton's laws are giving different results

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, reference-frames, spring

[image: DIAGRAM]

Imagine, there is an ideal spring obeying Hooke's law(initially at natural length) with balls(same mass) attached to its ends. Now the balls are simultaneously given a velocity of V perpendicular to the length of spring in opposite directions and the balls start rotating about their centre of mass. Now, after some time the spring will be in a stretched condition, thus some energy of the system is converted to spring energy and the velocity of balls is decreased. BUT, the spring force is always perpendicular to the velocity of the balls, therefore it won't change the velocity (magnitude)of the balls. So how is the velocity decreasing if there is no force in that direction?

Comment: There is a common relation you might remember: the acceleration towards the centre of rotation equals the square of the tangential velocity divided by the radius of rotation.

Answer (score 2):

> BUT, the spring force is always perpendicular to the velocity of the balls

This is incorrect. The spring force is always radial, but the motion of the balls is not only tangential. As the balls move outwards (or inwards later), part of the velocity is in the radial direction. This means the spring will do work and change the speed of the balls.

Answer (score 0):

The system remains centered on the origin as net external force is zero.You are right in assuming that the angular momentum(about the origin) is conserved. However this is not because the spring force is perpendicular to the velocity infact the spring force is almost never perpendicular to the velocity. If we consider the system of the two masses, the net external torque is zero. the spring force is an internal central force, thus the angular momentum is conserved.(Ref David Morin Introduction to Classical Mechanics).

Now if we allow the particle to be represented in polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$, the spring force is $-k(2r - l)$. the acceleration of the particle in the radial direction is the rate of change of radial velocity minus the centripetal acceleration, which is $\frac{d^2r}{dt^2} - \omega^2r $. where $\omega = \frac{d\theta}{dt}$. Applying newtons law in the radial direction we have $$ -k(2r - l) = m\frac{d^2r}{dt^2} - m\omega^2r$$.
Conservation of angular momentum gives $\omega = \frac{ul}{2r^2}$($u$ is the initial velocity). Substituting this in the newtons equation gives $$ kl -2kr + \frac{mu^2l^2}{4r^3} = m\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}$$
Which can be solved in principle for r, but way too messy to be shown here. The idea is take the term $\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}$ as $v\frac{dv}{dr}$, where $v = \frac{dr}{dt}$. thus we have converted a second order differential equation to a first order separable one.
What happens to the system can be explained qualitatively, initially, the spring force is too small to let the blocks go into circular motion, and thus they make the spring extend, until the radial velocity becomes zero. Then the spring contracts, until the radial velocity becomes zero again, so the system oscillates between contraction and expansion while rotating.